# Good approach to rotated exports in Sketch App

Tags: export, sketch-app

I created some artboards with mobile screens. The screens are all symbols, with more nested symbols and elements. I want to make a nice preview of my designs and I'd like to rotate my screens to give it a fun look, kind of like this guy did:

[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/4100490-Movie-Tickets-Booking]

However every time I try this, my edges look jagged or the images look very unsharp. The picture above doesn't seem to have this problem at all.

I tried flattening to bitmap; it results in an unsharp scale and jagged edges. I tried importing a symbol; it can't be scaled down easily. I tried exporting to photoshop and rotating there; even more horrible jagged edges and weird problems.

The best result I can manage to get:

1. Export artboard to .png at smaller size
2. Rotate png layer

But as you can see, it still leaves jagged edges:

[image]

I'm out of ideas on **how to achieve clean, non-jagged edges on rotation**, but I see so many people doing this. What is the best approach?

Comment: Are you viewing the images at 100%?  Is there any system zoom set on the device you are using?

Comment: Yes, viewing at 100%. No system zoom and the screenshot is also taken at 100% on a non-retina screen.

Comment: What happens if you export to png rather than taking a screenshot?  Is it any better?  If so that would suggest the problem is how the software renders for display purposes.

Comment: @BillyKerr Export looks exactly the same sadly.

Comment: What happens if you export the entire layout/scene as one PNG, including the background, not individual transparent PNGs.

Comment: @BillyKerr The same :( http://i63.tinypic.com/2n9jaqs.png

Comment: I don't know sketch, [this may be helpful](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/graphics-edgy-and-jagged-lines/11738/7) though.

Comment: Try a shallower angle, as per the example. It may be that the angle is exaggerating the aliasing.

Comment: @שelz that's Sketchup ;)